# using php to hide form code check

Tags: php, html, mysql, boolean

I think this is quite simple
I'm trying to hide a form if an event is full, this is my code:

```
var_dump($errorflag);
var_dump($registered , $limit);
if ($registered>$limit) {
$errorflag="1";
}
event=$event&eventlocation=$eventlocation&eventdate=$eventdate")
var_dump($errorflag);
```

and the code to hide the form:

```
?php  if ($errorflag=="1") {
          echo "style=\'display:none;\'";
      };
      ?>
```

Comment: I get this in the var dump: 
string(1) "0" string(2) "64" string(2) "10" string(1) "1"

but I'm not sure if it's reading the if statement or my code for hiding the form has a problem

Comment: Are you getting an error in the PHP logs?  What is the output of this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several syntax problems here. This line is ambiguous:

```
event=$event&eventlocation=$eventlocation&eventdate=$eventdate")
```

There's no $ before event - is that a variable? Also the line does not end with a ; but has a trailing ) that doesn't match any opening (.

Finally, this line:

```
?php if ($errorflag=="1") {
      echo "style=\'display:none;\'";
  };
```

Should be:

```
<?php if ($errorflag=="1") {
      echo "style=\'display:none;\'";
  } 
?>
```

Comment: that line is ambiguous, and it shouldn't be there, the code should read:
`var_dump($errorflag);
var_dump($registered , $limit);
if ($registered>$limit) {
$errorflag="1";
}

var_dump($errorflag);`

Comment: and i did remove the semi colon and still had the same thing happen

Comment: Did you add the < before ?php....? That character is somewhat crucial.